# Extract each column of a data frame into an object

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns, named `foo`, `bar`, etc.

**I would like to extract each column of the data frame to separate objects called `foo`, `bar` and so on. Is there an automated way to do this in R?**

Working example:

```
mock <- structure(list(
x = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
y = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
z = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output:

```
> mock
  x y z
1 1 A 0
2 2 B 0
3 3 C 1
```

How can I write a loop that creates objects `x`, `y` and `z` from the three columns of this data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> for (i in 1:ncol(mock)) {
+   assign(names(mock)[i],mock[,i])
+ }
> x
[1] 1 2 3
Levels: 1 2 3
> y
[1] A B C
Levels: A B C
> z
[1] 0 0 1
Levels: 0 1
```

You should be careful with the use of `assign`, though. You can achieve almost the same result using `attach(mock)`, which is reversible (`detach()`) and won't unintentionally overwrite existing variables (it just masks them).

Comment: It would be much safer if you ignored `attach` and instead used `with` or `within`. People who really understand `attach` don't use it.